# Best Practices for cache locality in Multicore Parallelism in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, functional-programming, parallel-processing, multicore

I'm studying multicore parallelism in F#.  I have to admit that immutability really helps to write correct parallel implementation.  However, it's hard to achieve good speedup and good scalability when the number of cores grows.  For example, my experience with Quick Sort algorithm is that many attempts to implement parallel Quick Sort in a purely functional way and using `List` or `Array` as the representation are failed.  Profiling those implementations shows that the number of cache misses increases significantly compared to those of sequential versions. However, if one implements parallel Quick Sort using mutation inside arrays, a good speedup could be obtained. Therefore, I think mutation might be a good practice for optimizing multicore parallelism.

I believe that [cache locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) is a big obstacle for multicore parallelism in a functional language. Functional programming involves in creating many short-lived objects; destruction of those objects may destroy coherence property of CPU caches. I have seen many suggestions how to improve cache locality in imperative languages, for example, [here](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/196902836) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/FalseSharing.aspx). But it's not clear to me how they would be done in functional programming, especially with recursive data structures such as trees, etc, which appear quite often.

*Are there any techniques to improve cache locality in an impure functional language (specifically F#)*? Any advices or code examples are more than welcome.

Comment: If your question really aims at impure functional languages, then the answers would be the same as for any procedural language, such as C#.

Comment: It's not the same. You may start with a pure implementation and optimize it using mutation later; I think this idea is fundamentally different from the imperative approach.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I can make out, the key to cache locality (multithreaded or otherwise) is

- Keep work units in a contiguous block of RAM that will fit into the cache

To this end ;

- *Avoid objects where possible*

  - Objects are allocated on the heap, and might be sprayed all over the place, depending on heap fragmentation, etc.
  - You have essentially zero control over the memory placement of objects, to the extent that the GC might move them at any time.
- Use arrays. Arrays are interpreted by most compilers as a contiguous block of memory.

  - Other collection datatypes might distribute things all over the place - linked lists, for example, are composed of pointers.
- Use arrays of primitive types. Object types are allocated on the heap, so an array of objects is just an array of pointers to objects that may be distributed all over the heap.
- Use arrays of structs, if you can't use primitives. Structs have their fields arranged sequentially in memory, and are treated as primitives by the .NET compilers.
- Work out the size of the cache on the machine you'll be executing it on

  - CPUs have different size L2 caches
  - It might be prudent to design your code to scale with different cache sizes
  - Or more simply, write code that will fit inside the lowest common cache size your code will be running on
- Work out what needs to sit close to each datum

  - In practice, you're not going to fit your whole working set into the L2 cache
  - Examine (or redesign) your algorithms so that the data structures you are using hold data that's needed "next" close to data that was previously needed.

In practice this means that you may end up using data structures that are not theoretically perfect examples of computer science - but that's all right, computers aren't theoretically perfect examples of computer science either.

A good academic paper on the subject is [Cache-Efficient String Sorting Using Copying](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/~rsinha/papers/SinhaRingZobel-2006.pdf)

Comment: I'm surprise that no one upvotes this post. Your answer is great because it mentions many good points about cache locality in a managed environment. I like your idea of not theoretically perfect data structures, my experience shows that sometimes they are the best in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing mutability within functions in F# is a blessing, but it should only be used when optimizing code.  Purely-functional style often yields more intuitive implementation, and hence is preferred.

Here's what a quick search returned: [Parallel Quicksort in Haskell](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/parallel-generic-quicksort-in-haskell.html).  Let's keep the discussion about performance focused on performance.  Choose a processor, then bench it with a specific algorithm.

To answer your question without specifics, I'd say that [Clojure](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html)'s approach to implementing [STM](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) could be a lesson in general case on how to decouple paths of execution on multicore processors and improve cache locality.  But it's only effective when number of reads outweigh number of writes.

Comment: The Haskell link doesn't really have anything to do with cache locality, and is also a rather biased article. Idiomatic array sorting in Haskell would be better achieved via the e.g. [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-algorithms/0.4/doc/html/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Merge.html) package.

Comment: @Don Stewart: how is your link related to the effort to use parallel computation to sort?  Could you also point out what makes you feel that linked blog entry is biased?

Comment: I would agree, but I feel there's a good starting point for OP there.  BTW, John Harrop's book is pretty excellent, so I'd use his blog as a solid reference any day. http://www.amazon.com/F-Scientists-Jon-Harrop/dp/0470242116

Comment: I have a similar opinion about Monads in Haskell, but I agree that it's just an opinion.  I prefer the focused way in which Monads are presented in F#.

Comment: Mutability is not just a blessing. I care about performance, if I have to sacrifice some readability and convenience to achieve performance, it worths to do though.

Comment: @pad: IMHO the fundamental difference between Haskell's and F#'s mutable state is in the way it's implemented syntactically.  In Haskell they have special objects for that, in F# -- a special syntax.  Both are searchable/discoverable in code, and that sets them apart from the likes of c++/c#/java.  Personally, I prefer F#'s way, since it keeps things together.

Comment: @pad: Haskell is trying to spin its own version of a run-time, whereas F# is relying on existing IL technology.  It's completely possible that end-game is faster in one over the other due to some esoteric trick in JITter that's available here but not there.  My preference stays with optimizations that are still readable.  I think it's easier to accomplish in F#.

Comment: Good to hear it, I'm also positive about optimization for parallelism in F#. But I think those optimizations are not widely known, that is the reason for this question.

Comment: @pad: It's generally hard to get parallelism right.  I feel that tuning an algorithm for performance with parallelism requires careful testing.  There are products such as CHESS (fuzz) and Jinx that allow to detect a change in behavior when code is executed on multi-core.  Also, F#'s AsyncBuilder Monad can be externally-configured, so that a suite of tests can be built in single-threaded scenario, and then parallelization can be tested with a single-line code change.

Comment: "Purely-functional style often yields more intuitive implementation, and hence is preferred". Sometimes but not always. In many cases there is no significant difference, e.g. linear algebra, state machines. In some cases, there are no known intuitive pure solutions, e.g. graph algorithms, type inference.

Answer (score 3):

I am no parallelism expert, but here is my advice anyway.

1. I would expect that a locally mutable approach where each core is allocated an area of memory which is both read and written will always beat a pure approach.
2. Try to formulate your algorithm so that it works sequentially on a contiguous area of memory. This means that if you are working with graphs, it may be worth "flattening" nodes into arrays and replace references by indices before processing. Regardless of cache locality issues, this is always a good optimisation technique in .NET, as it helps keep garbage collection out of the way.

Comment: "it may be worth "flattening" nodes into arrays and replace references by indices before processing". Aka avoid boxing.

Answer (score 3):

A great approach is to split the work into smaller sections and iterate over each section on each core.

One option I would start with is to look for cache locality improvements on a single core before going parallel, it should be simply a matter of subdividing the work again for each core.  For example if you are doing matrix calculations with large matrices then you could split up the calculations into smaller sections.

Heres a great example of that: [Cache Locality For Performance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2009/06/22/cache-locality-for-performance.aspx)

There were some great sections in Tomas Petricek's book **Real Work functional programming**, check out Chapter 14 Writing Parallel Functional Programs, you might find Parallel processing of a binary tree of particular interest.

Comment: I have read the chapter, the idea of parallel processing in a binary tree is compelling but in my opinion it's still sensitive to cache locality.

Answer (score 2):

To write scalable Apps cache locality is paramount to your application speed. The principles are well explain by [Scott Meyers](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/cpu-caches-and-why-you-care) talk. Immutability does not play well with cache locality since you create new objects in memory which forces the CPU to reload the data from the new object again. 
As in the talk is noted even on modern CPUs the L1 cache has only 32 KB size which is shared for code and data between all cores. If you go multi threaded you should try to consume as little memory as possible (goodbye immutabilty) to stay in the fastest cache. The L2 cache is about 4-8 MB which is much bigger but still tiny compared to the data you are trying to sort.

If you manage to write an application which consumes as little memory as possible (data cache locality) you can get speedups of 20 or more. But if you manage this for 1 core it might be very well be that scaling to more cores will hurt performance since all cores are competing for the same L2 cache.

To get most out of it the C++ guys use PGA (Profile Guided Optimizations) which allows them to profile their application which is used as input data for the compiler to emit better optimized code for the specific use case.

You can get better to certain extent in a managed code but since so many factors influence your cache locality it is not likely that you will ever see a speedup of 20 in the real world due to total cache locality. This remains the regime of C++ and compilers which use profiling data.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Though your post doesn't directly answer my question, it is helpful for cache-aware programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

You may get some ideas from these:

Cache-Oblivious http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cacheObliviousBTree.html [Cache-Oblivious Search Trees Project](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cacheObliviousBTree.html)

[DSapce@MIT Cache coherence strategies in a many-core processor](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/61276) http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/61276

[describes the revolutionary idea of cache oblivious algorithms via the elegant and efficient implementation of a matrix multiply in F#.](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/search/label/cache%20oblivious)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Actually I have read some of them. They're still far from F#'s idioms. The post about cache oblivious matrix multiply in F# used array mutation, and I'm looking for other ideas than that.

Comment: @pad "They're still far from F#'s idioms". I disagree.

Comment: @JonHarrop: I know that cache-oblivious algorithms are state-of-the-art. I just want to see something done in F#.

Comment: @pad "cache-oblivious algorithms are state-of-the-art". They were originally described in Harold Prokop's seminal Masters thesis in 1999.